# Missing iOS distribution signing identity for ........ xcode 7.2

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9, xcode7.2

I am new for the iOS development and I want to test my iOS app using new device. I using "save for ad hoc deployment" for creating project archive. But, error massage is "Missing ios distribution signing identity for (company name)". I'll really appreciate for your answers for solve this issue.

Comment: What efforts have *you* made to understand and solve this issue?

Comment: I installed the keychain for Apple WWDRCA certificate : https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/, but issue is still same.

Comment: Read through a highly recommended [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)